# Код 500 при ajax-отправке формы на роут

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-2

А вдруг кто сталкивался? При сабмите формы аякс начал возвращать **`код 500`**.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/callback-message',
```

Собсно роут на месте

```
'callback-message' => array(
        'type'    => 'literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/callback-message',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'App\Controller\Contact',
                'action'     => 'callback'
```

Акшон в контроллере то же на месте

```
class ContactController extends Controller {

    public function callbackAction() {
```

.htaccess в пределах стандартного для zf2

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://lasertech.com.ua/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

**UPD.:**

**`hxr`** бросает **`Internal Server Error`**

**`права`** на папки и файлы норм.

**`лог хоста`** (хотя вся файловая структура на месте!):

```
Cannot serve directory /var/www/lasertech/lasertech.com.ua/app/module/App/src/App/Controller/: No matching DirectoryIndex
```

Trinity! Help!

Comment: Код 500 означает, что у вас где-то fatal error в php-скрипте или файле .htaccess. Проверьте логи и исправьте ошибки.

Comment: "No matching DirectoryIndex" встречался, если в вирт.хосте/htaccess реально не был задан DirectoryIndex. Проверяли?

Comment: @psaproxy вы при этом наверное получали 403, верно? А тут 500.